# Show Text Selecting Bar by default in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I show the Text Selecting Bar by default in Flutter without the user actually long pressing or double tapping in the Text Area? I am trying all possibilities in SelectableText Widget and similar, but, its not working. Could anyone help me with this?
[image: The Selector should be enabled like this so that user could comprehend that text area is selectable and is draggable.]

Answer (score 0):

For an example, I have A `TextEditingController` called `myController`:

```
    TextField(
    controller: myController,
    onTap: () => myController.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: _controller.value.text.length),
    )
```

basicaly, you need to set the selection property with a `TextSelection` from the `baseOffset` to the `extentOffset`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
However, the selecting draggable bar is only visible after onTap. I wanted to show those draggable bars by default with the textfield, not after onTap.
Thank you again!

Comment: No, I showed you an example to do it, you can take it wherever you want, just make sure that controller is linked to the TextField

Comment: Yes, And, already tried with same ditto code, but the text Selector does not show until we long press or double tap.